# Rewrite Endpoints not Indexing with google

Tags: endpoints

I don't know if anyone else has found this, but I've created some Endpoints for Authors to now have several pages, but Google isn't seeing any of them.

It seems to see the parent url, but not any of the endpoints.

Anyone had this issue or know if endpoints need something extra to be seen?

Hopefully thats not too vague.